# PHPStorm -> Sublime Text mac shortcuts

Tags: php, macos, phpstorm

I have googling around for this, but have not found the answer.

I have just gone from sublime text to PHPStorm.

Is there any similar shortcuts for selecting variable (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), multiple cursor etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -  both features are available in PHPStrom 8.0 EAP: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/. Select Next Occurrence action (mapped to Cmd+G in default MacOSX keymap) works pretty much in the same way as Ctrl+D in Sublime.

Answer (score 1):

In the preferences window, search for ”Add Selection for Next Occurence” (PhpStorm 8.0.1)

On mac the default is ctrl+G, but you can change it to ctrl+D (or cmd+D on mac)